# iframe a URL without exact path file name?

Tags: html, iframe

I'm wanting to iframe `http://192.155.83.120:5000/r/2` onto another page - but as I just found out, because the URL doesn't generate anything like index.html - it isn't supported, and the iframe shows blank.

I'm not entirely sure if there is a way to generate the same page in this ruby app as index.html or something similar - would somebody have a workaround?

Comment: @copyflake iframe url doesnt have to be with something like index.html...

Comment: @YardenST - you're probably right, but I can't seem to iframe [http://192.155.83.120:5000/r/2] and I was told that if it had index.html on the end, it would've worked.

Answer (score 0):

The web page in its headers returns:

```
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
```

That means, that unless you share same domain & port & protocol, you cannot put it inside an iframe on your site.

Comment: I can't seem to locate that in the page's header?

Comment: @copyflake by headers,I mean HTTP HEADERS, not the HTML header on the page. if you use Chrome you can open the console, go to network tab and see the response headers.. (im not familiar with others browsers so much)

Comment: I understand now. Thanks for filling me in on this. Would you know what I might have to do, either in the page code or on the server (it's being hosted on a linux VPS), to get it set to "ALLOW-FROM uri"?

Comment: @copyflake it could be you web server, or at your code base... you should check both

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. According to Mozilla developer docs, ALLOW-FROM isn't well supported. Chrome doesn't support it, IE doesn't really, Safari doesn't at all.

Kinda rules that out then. I'll have to try and get the ruby app and the website hosted on the same server then. I'll assume that would fix the problem.